# How to install Scribus

Tags: command-line

I want to install and use the scribus application. I am using Xubuntu 18.04 as primary OS on a Dell 3162 notebook computer.

Comment: Read the documentation on their homepage and wiki.

Answer (score 3):

To install Scribus, open the Ubuntu Software center. Search for "Scribus" and click the entry that appears. You then can start the install with the "Install" button.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it by:

1. Update packages information: `sudo apt-get update`
2. Install it using `sudo apt-get install scribus`

Comment: Scribus is already in the Ubuntu Repositories, so it seems fair to make clear that adding the PPA is optional, not required.